# Writing a function to replace duplicate files with hardlinks

Tags: linux, bash

I need to write a bash script that iterates through the files of a specified directory and replaces duplicates of files with hardlinks. Right now, my entire function looks like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
# sameln --- remove duplicate copies of files in specified directory

D=$1
cd $D           #go to directory specified as default input

fileNum=0       #loop counter

DIR=".*|*"
for f in $DIR           #for every file in the directory
do
    files[$fileNum]=$f      #save that file into the array
    fileNum=$((fileNum+1))      #increment the counter
done

for((j=0; j<$fileNum; j++))             #for every file
do
    if [ -f "$files[$j]" ]          #access that file in the array
    then
        for((k=0; k<$fileNum; k++))     #for every other file
        do
            if [ -f "$files[$k]" ]      #access other files in the array
            then
                test[cmp -s ${files[$j]} ${files[$k]}]      #compare if the files are identical
                [ln ${files[$j]} ${files[$k]}]          #change second file to a hard link
            fi
        done
    fi
done
```

Basically:

- Loop through all files of depth 1 in specified directory
- Put file contents into array
- Compare each array item with every other array item and replace duplicates with hardlinks

The test directory has four files: a, b, c, d

a and b are different, but c and d are duplicates (they are empty). After running the script, ls -l shows that all of the files still only have 1 hardlink, so the script appears to have basically done nothing.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Run your script with `bash -x scriptname` first, you might spot the error right away. - Your loop over the files doesn't work so the script can't do anything.

Comment: Out of `a, b, c & d` which filename will you keep, and how do you determine that? If `c` and `d` are identical, but have different filenames, which will you create hardlinks to? Which will you remove? Currently 'change the second file' doesn't guarantee any particular order. You should skip the comparison if `$j -eq $k`, e.g. `[ $j -eq $k ] && continue` before `test cmp...`

Comment: There's already dedicated software that does this, by the way. I'd consider leveraging that, rather than trying to reinvent this wheel.

Answer (score 1):

```
DIR=".*|*"
for f in $DIR           #for every file in the directory
do
    echo $f
done
```

This code outputs

```
.*|*
```

You should not loop over files like this. Look into the `find` command. As you see, your code doesn't work because the first loop is already faulty.

BTW, don't name your variables all uppercase, those are reserved for system variables, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

You may be making this process a bit harder on yourself than necessary. There is already a Linux command `fdupes` that scans a directory conducting a byte-by-byte, md5sum, date & time comparison to determine whether files are duplicates of one another. It can easily find and return groups of files that are duplicates. Your are left with only using the results.

Below is a quick example of using this tool for the job. **NOTE** this quick example works only for filenames that **do not** contain spaces within them. You will have to modify it if you are dealing with filenames containing spaces. This is intended to show an approach to using a tool that already does what you want. Also **note** the actual `ln` command is commented out below. The program just prints what it would do. After testing you can remove the comment to the `ln` command once you are satisfied with the results.

```
#! /bin/bash
# sameln --- remove duplicate copies of files in specified directory using fdupes

[ -d "$1" ] || {                  # test valid directory supplied
    printf "error: invalid directory '%s'.  usage: %s <dir>\n" "$1" "${0//\//}"
    exit 1
}

type fdupes &>/dev/null || {      # verify fdupes is available in path
    printf "error: 'fdupes' required. Program not found within your path\n"
    exit 1
}

pushd "$1" &>/dev/null            # go to directory specified as default input

declare -a files                  # declare files and dupes array
declare -a dupes

## read duplicate files into files array
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -a files < <(fdupes --sameline .)

## for each list of duplicates
for ((i = 0; i < ${#files[@]}; i++)); do

    printf "\n duplicate files   %s\n\n" "${files[i]}"

    ## split into original files (no interal 'spaces' allowed in filenames)
    dupes=( ${files[i]} )

    ## for the 1st duplicate on
    for ((j = 1; j < ${#dupes[@]}; j++)); do

        ## create hardlink to original (actual command commented)
        printf "   ln -f %s %s\n" "${dupes[0]}" "${dupes[j]}"
        # ln -f "${dupes[0]}" "${dupes[j]}"

    done

done

exit 0
```

**Output/Example**

```
$ bash rmdupes.sh dat

 duplicate files   ./output.dat ./tmptest ./env4.dat.out

   ln -f ./output.dat ./tmptest
   ln -f ./output.dat ./env4.dat.out

 duplicate files   ./vh.conf ./vhawk.conf

   ln -f ./vh.conf ./vhawk.conf

 duplicate files   ./outfile.txt ./newfile.txt

   ln -f ./outfile.txt ./newfile.txt

 duplicate files   ./z1 ./z1cpy

   ln -f ./z1 ./z1cpy
```

Comment: Please, do it right. `IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -a files < <(fdupes --sameline .)` (intentionally no `-r` on the `read`, since `fdupes` adds backslash-escaping when used with `--sameline`).

Comment: ...that avoids glob expansion when string-splitting content into the array, and also means you don't need to mess around with changing IFS on separate lines.

Comment: I'd also consider replacing `which` with `type` to avoid depending on external tools. And there's no point at all to the final `popd` before exit, since current directory isn't inherited by parent processes anyhow.

Comment: I'm always amazed at the number of pebbles you hold in your hand. One day I will have snatched most, but not all. Thanks Charles!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy what is the downside to using a **here string** in this situation? e.g. `IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -a files <<<"$(fdupes --sameline .)"`

Comment: The herestring is fine too. (A herestring does add a terminating newline to the content fed via it, if one doesn't already exist -- sometimes that matters, but this isn't one of those cases).

Comment: BTW, passing `-L` to fdupes will have it replace duplicates with hardlinks itself -- no need for any of this scripting.

Comment: I saw that, but I have it as `-l hard` or `--link=hard`, the `-o` or `--order=(time|name)` gives some control over the order in which the duplicates are processed. Looks like the only time the additional script would be necessary is if you needed more control over what to do with each file. Thanks.