# Function to replace duplicate files with hardlinks

Tags: linux, bash

I need to write a bash script that iterates through the files of a specified directory and replaces duplicates of files with hardlinks.

So far, I have iterated through the files and stored the file names in an array.

Now, I need to go through that array and check each file for any duplicates. The relevant code that I'm using to do this is below:

```
#"files" is the array with all the file names
#"fileNum" is the size of the array

...

for((j=0; j<$fileNum; j++))             #for every file
do
    if [ -f "$files[$j]" ]          #access that file in the array
    then
        for((k=0; k<$fileNum; k++))     #for every other file
        do
            if [ -f "$files[$k]" ]      #access other files in the array
            then
                test[cmp -s ${files[$j]} ${files[$k]}]      #compare if the files are identical
                [ln ${files[$j]} ${files[$k]}]          #change second file to a hard link
            fi
...
```

The test directory has two files: a and b. b is a copy of a.

After running the script, ls -l shows that all of the files still only have 1 hardlink, so the script appears to have basically done nothing.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Upvote for only showing the relevant part of your code. Good question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, don't iterate over all files twice otherwise you will compare each couple twice and you will compare a file against itself. Secondly, dollar signs are not required inside `(( ))`. Finally, I don't think you access the array correctly, so the `[ -f ]` always fails and hence nothing happens. Note that this requires a change in your first loop as well (the array notation when using `[ -f ]`.

The second loop, instead, should be like this:

```
for((k=j+1; k<fileNum; k++)); do
    if [ -f ${files["$k"]} ]; then
        cmp ${files["$j"]} ${files["$k"]}
        if [[ "$?" -eq 0 ]]; then
            rm  ${files["$k"]}
            ln ${files["$j"]} ${files["$k"]}
        fi
    fi
done
```

If the `cmp` here succeeds it will create a link. `cmp` only fails when the files differ. Try this code and let me know when you have any problems.

Alternatively:

```
for((k=j+1; k<fileNum; k++)); do
    if [ -f ${files["$k"]} ]; then
        cmp ${files["$j"]} ${files["$k"]} && ln -f ${files["$j"]} ${files["$k"]}
    fi
done
```

Comment: It has a minor error - it's trying to create a hardlink with an existing file name, so I think you have to delete the file name before creating the hardlink. I am trying to correct this right now with if [#cmp = true] then [ delete file, create hardlink], but I am getting an error that states that the first if statement needs a binary operator

Comment: Updated, if it's incorrect, `rm` the other file. I was just guessing which one to delete haha. - Don't forget to accept and upvote if the answer is to your liking.

Comment: BTW you can also just use `ln -f` that will automatically remove the target file if it exists!

Comment: Thank you for answering this, along with my other questions

Comment: Actually, I found a mistake - isn't it necessary to iterate over all files twice? because the alternate code block only iterates over everything once, it only checks for duplicates against one file - the j variable is never updated

Comment: Do tell, what appears to be the problem?

Comment: For example, if I have a, b, and c, where b and c are duplicates, the code fails.

Comment: Try `if [ cmp b c ]; then echo 'equal'; else echo 'not equal'; fi` - Which files fail?

Comment: This returns an error -  it is asking for a binary operator for the if-statement

Comment: Try to add `echo ${files["$j"]} ${files["$k"]}` the line right before the `cmp`. This is a great tip overall, add `echo` statements to check your progress and debug.

Comment: I enclosed your alternate code in an outer for loop incrementing j and it worked

Comment: `$?` contains the exit code of the last command (0 if successful), it's a very useful variable!

Comment: With bash `"${files[j]}"` and `"${files[k]}"` is sufficient for array access. In this case array syntax acts like `$((...))` where `$` isn't required for internal reference.

Comment: I found it slick when I ran across it. Just a FYI, I ran tests regarding the `cmp` solution and the `fdupes` solution. I don't know how `fdupes` does it, but using `fdupes` is some `500` times faster than using `cmp`. Example: above code on test dir `real    0m22.221s`, `fdupes` script performing same operation `real    0m0.044s`. I was fairly amazed.

Comment: Wow, an incredible speed up indeed! What `fdupes` solution are you talking about btw?

Comment: He asked another similar/identical question. I'll see if I can find it. [**Writing a function to replace duplicate files with hardlinks**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29585233/writing-a-function-to-replace-duplicate-files-with-hardlinks) which I took a crack at with `fdupes` that Charles had to help smooth the rough edges on. (you answered that one too.)